# Checking to see if path is in url

Tags: php

I have a path that I want to check for in a url. How would I isolate

'pages/morepages/'
http://www.mypage.com/pages/morepages/

I've tried running a parse url function on my url and then I get the path. I don't know how to access that key in that array though. For example..

```
$url = 'http://www.mypage.com/pages/morepages/';

print_r(parse_url($url));

if ($url['path'] == '/pages/morepages/') {
    echo 'This works.';
};
```

I want to run an if conditional on if that path exists, but I am having trouble accessing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for one string within another, [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) will work pretty well.

```
echo strpos( $url, $path ) !== false ? 'Exists' : 'Does Not Exist' ;
```

Comment: Quoting the docs: `If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.`

Comment: @Tom Good point. I'll have to stop using `strstr` in my personal projects ;) Answer updated.

Comment: this is not correct. strpos can return 0, you must use !== false. edited

Comment: You are right. I must use the !== syntax. This is the correct answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

something like find in string ?

```
if ( strpos($url['path'], '/pages/morepages/') !== false ){
//echo "this works";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
$url = 'http://www.mypage.com/pages/morepages/';

    if (strpos($url, '/pages/morepages/') !== false) {
        echo "found";
    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
if (parse_url($url['path'], PHP_URL_PATH) == '/pages/morepages/') {
    echo 'This works.';
} // No semicolon
```

It's probably better to use `strpos()` though, which is a LOT faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign function's result to any variable:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);

if ($parts['path'] == '/pages/morepages') {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse_url needs to return something to a new array variable. So use:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url));

if ($parsedUrl['path'] == '/pages/morepages/') {
    echo 'This works.';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the output of `parse_url` to a variable. `$url` is still equal to the string (`parse_url` returns an array, it doesn't modify the string passed in).

`$url = parse_url($url);`